# How to draw a triangle Mesh in VisualStudio 2022 Community Edition 17.5.4. in 2023?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF project (.NET7) in visual studio on Windows 11.

I want to draw a triangle with its normal in a `Viewport3D` area. The window opens but I don't see anything except white background. I also tried to add a camera and point it in different directions, but that didn't help.

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">   
</Application>
```

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Viewport3D Name="viewport3D"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(0, 0, -1));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(0, 1, -1));
            mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(1, 0, -1));
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
            mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);

            GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red));

            ModelVisual3D visual = new ModelVisual3D();
            visual.Content = model;

            viewport3D.Children.Add(visual);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please provide a minimal example of a 3D triangle being rendered in a viewport3D?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but as a suggestion: For reasons I can't remember, a long time ago I moved away from Viewport3D to Helix Toolkit (open source).  It was probably because of the built in quality of life features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that you haven't drawn the reverse side of your triangle, be sure to add the same indices again, in reverse order (the order determines which side will render).

This code should work:

```
MeshGeometry3D mesh = new MeshGeometry3D();
mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(-5, -5, 0));
mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(5, -5, 0));
mesh.Positions.Add(new Point3D(0, 5, 0));

//Add one side of the triangle
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);

//Add the reverse side of the triangle
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(2);
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(1);
mesh.TriangleIndices.Add(0);

GeometryModel3D model = new GeometryModel3D(mesh, new DiffuseMaterial(Brushes.Red));

ModelVisual3D visual = new ModelVisual3D();
visual.Content = model;

viewport3D.Children.Add(visual);

//Light the scene, otherwise everything will be black
var light = new ModelVisual3D();
light.Content = new AmbientLight(Colors.White);
viewport3D.Children.Add(light);

//Set the camera on the Z axis looking back to origin   
var camera = new PerspectiveCamera(
  position: new Point3D(0, 0, -40),
  lookDirection: new Vector3D(0, 0, 1),
  upDirection: new Vector3D(0, 1, 0),
  fieldOfView: 60);
camera.NearPlaneDistance = 1;
camera.FarPlaneDistance = 100;
viewport3D.Camera = camera;
```

However, I'm getting very weird rending and the rendering changes as I resize the window:
[image]

EDIT:
For some reason, changing the XAML to include `RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"` fixed my rendering:

```
<Viewport3D Name="viewport3D" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" />
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for me. Lucky for me, it didn't even need the Aliased option. Further testing revealed, I don't need to draw the back of the triangle. So maybe it was just the wrong camera settings afterall? I will investiage further and come back to this.